Почему не работает apt update?
Пытаюсь установить Zabbix. При использовании команды apt update происходит следующее. Я не понимаю что это и как исправить? Дистрибутив дебиан ставился с DVD образа без использования интернета.


Надо или примонтировать установочный диск или лучше заменить источники на сетевые.

А как заменить на сетевые?

https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

В Debian и других основанных на Debian дистрибутивах репозитории — это серверы, на которых хранятся пакеты программного обеспечения, доступные для установки и обновления. Репозитории позволяют системе получать обновления, новые пакеты и исправления безопасности.
Типы репозиториев
Основные репозитории:

Main: Содержит свободно распространяемое программное обеспечение,
которое соответствует политике свободного ПО Debian.

Contrib: Содержит свободно распространяемое программное обеспечение,
которое может иметь зависимости от несвободного ПО.

Non-Free: Содержит несвободное программное обеспечение, которое не
соответствует политике свободного ПО Debian.


Репозитории обновлений:

Security Updates: Содержит исправления безопасности для пакетов в
основном репозитории.
Backports: Содержит более новые версии пакетов из будущих релизов,
адаптированные для текущего стабильного релиза.
Сторонние репозитории:
Репозитории, предоставляемые сторонними разработчиками или
компаниями, например, репозитории для определенных программ или
библиотек.

Настройка репозиториев
 Редактирование sources.list
Файл sources.list находится в директории /etc/apt/ и содержит список репозиториев, из которых система получает пакеты.
Пример настройки sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

А то, что касается CD-ROM закоментировать или удалить.( Перед редактированием рекомендуется сделать резервную копию файла sources.list)
После редактирования sources.list или добавления новых репозиториев нужно обновить список пакетов:
apt update

Я не знаю, имеется ли Zabbix в репозиториях Debian, или нужно добавить сторонние репозитории. Подробней https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList
